# angular-kendo in Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to use [angular-kendo](http://goo.gl/MVb7BE) in a Dart application. Any ideas on how to make this happen? Currently when in include angular-kendo.js in the html file i get

'Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: angular is not defined'

Here is my html file:

```dart
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Business portal app</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<body>

<select kendo-drop-down-list>
  <option value="1">Thing 1</option>
  <option value="2">Thing 2</option>
  <option value="3">Thing 3</option>
</select>
<!-------------------  Javascript Includes ---------------------->
        <script src="../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="../lib/kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/angular-kendo/angular-kendo.js"></script>
        <script type="application/dart" src="business_portal_app.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script> -->

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the dart file:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

class MyAppModule extends Module {
    BusinessPortalModule() {

    }
}

void main() {
    ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: angular-kendo directives/components are written in JavaScript and won't work with AngularDart. You have to add the AngularJS dependency - see @ChristoperMarshall s anwer. AFAIK AngularJS and AngularDart won't work simultaneously on the same page. angular-kendo directives need to be ported to AngularDart to work without AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the angular dependency

[From the Docs](http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/)

To use Angular-Kendo, you **need to include the angular-kendo.js file in your page BELOW Angular and Kendo UI.** Don't forget that Kendo UI depends on jQuery, so you are going to need that too:

```dart
<script src="js/angular-1.0.5.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure your app name is defined.

**E.g**

```dart
<html ng-app="myAppName">
```